# How to subscribe to src Change of Iframe in Angular 7

Tags: angular, iframe

We are Looking for a way to subscribe to the src (url) change from an IFrame inside an Angular 7 Application. Is there a way to intercept the src Change?

Comment: maybe the with the load event of the iframe? Or MutationObserver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the RxJS fromEvent constructor to take the 'load' event from the iFrame and subscribe to its changes. You can use the RxJS skip operator to ignore the initial load event if you need to.

Here's the gist of what you can do, but I've linked a full stackblitz example at the bottom of the answer too.

```
@ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    fromEvent(this.iframe.nativeElement, 'load')
      // Skip the initial load event and only capture subsequent events.
      .pipe(skip(1))
      .subscribe((event: Event) => console.log(event.target));
}
```

Skip Docs:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/skip.html

From Event Docs:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html

Full StackBlitz Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxmbgp

Comment: Note, this is better than to use the `load()` method, as the method may be triggered twice

Answer (score 7):

Actually it's simpler than you think, and you don't even need `fromEvent` and `rxjs`.
Just listen to the `load` event like this:

```
<iframe [src]="src" (load)="test()"></iframe>
```

This is a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hynfrf?file=src/app/app.component.html)

And if you want the iframe reference you can easily get it also without ViewChild:

```
<iframe #frame [src]="src" (load)="test(frame)"></iframe>
```

Comment: the `load()` method may be triggered twice, which may create some unexpected errors